# Frontend editor in joomla 3 does not load the assigned position

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Well I use the new feature [frontend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAQYCUeGZkE&feature=youtu.be) editor in joomla 3.4 and works well with a single template (protostar - default).

I need to use multiple templates on my site. Then copy the protostar template, delete I do not need and protostar2 name, just place a call position position-80.

***Template protostar2***

**Index.php**

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://j2.travelsolution.mx/templates/protostar/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://j2.travelsolution.mx/templates/protostar/js/template.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body class="site ">


    <div class="body">
        <div class="container">



            <div class="row-fluid">

                <main id="content" role="main" >
                    <jdoc:include type="component" />
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-80" />

                </main>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**templateDetails.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 2.5//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/2.5/template-install.dtd">
<extension version="3.1" type="template" client="site">
    <name>protostar2</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <creationDate>4/30/2012</creationDate>
    <author>Kyle Ledbetter</author>
    <authorEmail>admin@joomla.org</authorEmail>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <description>TPL_PROTOSTAR2_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <files>
        <folder>css</folder>    
        <folder>js</folder>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>

    </files>
    <positions>
        <position>position-80</position>
    </positions>

</extension>
```

When I modify the module from the frontend everything is OK, except that the position section only loads the positions of protostar and not protostar2 position-80 appears. Now if I change the module (position 80) from the backend it works perfect. Here a [picture](http://s1.postimg.org/9pbjevzvz/Untitled_1.jpg).

In short.
I have 2 templates: protostar (Default) and protostar2.
I created a menu (m2) and assigned the protostar2, then I did my module and assign the position-80. To edit from the frontend load not the position I-80

What I need place to load the correct position?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution editing the file default.php in line 110 I comment :

```
//echo $this->loadTemplate('positions');
```

Whith this does not load the positions and solved my problem.
The file is allocated in **YOUR_PATH_SITE\components\com_config\view\modules\tmpl\default.php**